# Problem with fprintf() in "at" mode while printing structs

Tags: c, file, printf

I have  a problem when executing my code, at certain point the program ends when there's still code to run. I have a struct called `Cliente`, I allocate memory for it at the end of the case in order to save information into a file. The part of retrieving data works fine, the problem comes when it has to save the information into the file via `fprintf()`. Thank you in advance.

Here is the struct `Cliente`

```
typedef struct {
    char  *dni;
    char *nombre;
    Fecha fechaNac;
    char *direccion;
    char *telefono;
}Cliente;
```

And this is the piece of code im trying to be ran using a menu input:

```
Cliente *c;

case '2':
        c = (Cliente*) malloc(sizeof(Cliente)); //Reservo memoria
        fInfoCliente = fopen("..\\Cliente\\InfoClientes.txt", "a");
        fflush(stdin);

        if (fInfoCliente == NULL) {
            printf("\nError al abrir el archivo\n\n");
            menuCliente();
        } else {
            printf("Introduzca la siguiente informacion sobre el cliente:\n");
            printf("\nNombre: ");
            gets(c->nombre);
            printf("DNI: ");
            gets(c->dni);
            printf("Fecha de Nacimiento (DDMMAAAA): ");
            scanf("%i/%i/%i", &c->fechaNac.dia, &c->fechaNac.mes, &c->fechaNac.anyo);

            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Direccion: ");
            gets(c->direccion);
            printf("Telefono: ");
            gets(c->telefono);


            printf("Antes si");
            fprintf(fInfoCliente, "%s", c->nombre);//, c->dni, c->fechaNac.dia, c->fechaNac.mes, c->fechaNac.anyo, c->direccion, c->telefono); ,%s,%i,%i,%i,%s,%s
            printf("Despues no");

            printf("\nDesea añadir otro cliente? (Y/n)");
            scanf("%c", opc);

            fclose(fInfoCliente);
            free(c);
        }
        break;
```

Comment: 1. You never allocate memory for the strings you read via `gets`. You pass uninitialized pointers to `gets` causing undefined behaviour. 2. Do not use `gets`. use `fgets` instead.

Comment: You should initialize the pointers that you pass to `gets`, e.g. `c->nombre = malloc(10); gets(c->nombre);`. Also, use `fgets()` in preference to `gets()` because the latter will corrupt your memory if you get more input than expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allocating any memory for those strings you're reading in.  All the `char*` members of the structure you allocated are just uninitialized pointers.

Also `fflush(stdin)` is a bad idea.